# Why this line NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(...) throws SIGABRT

Tags: swift, nsnotificationcenter, xcode6

I am playing with NSNotificationCenter in swift. This is my code in `main.swift`

import Foundation

```
class T: NSObject {

    func someAction(notification: NSNotification) {
        println(notification.userInfo)
    }
}

var dataDict = Dictionary<String, String>()
dataDict["test"] = "test"
dataDict["test1"] = "test1"


var t = T();
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(t, selector:"someAction", name: "someAction", object:nil)



NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("someAction", object:nil, userInfo:dataDict)

let runloop = NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop();
runloop.run();

println("Done");
```

At the line `postNotification`, I got an exception:

[image]

Here is some stacktrace:

```
2014-07-24 08:58:59.959 testswiftcli2[2171:303] -[_TtC13testswiftcli21T someAction]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1005005a0
2014-07-24 08:58:59.961 testswiftcli2[2171:303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_TtC13testswiftcli21T someAction]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1005005a0'
```

When I tried to inspect the instance, I got this:

```
(lldb) po 0x1005005a0
4300211616
```

It seems like the variable has already gone out of scope. Is it a right conclusion?

What is the problem with the code above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The selector should be `someAction:` instead of `someAction` because it has one argument.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! It works. So how should I interpret the po output? Did the instance t go out of scope?